# Simple XHR long polling without jQuery

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, long-polling

I am trying to wite a simple long polling system (yep, I do **not** want to use any ready-made scipt, as I want to learn from it). I am using a node server where I can easily pipe/write my data back to the client without calling `result.end();`. How should I do this client side? I just want this as a simple and not really good fallback for users using ie<=9, as the better browsers get a fast and easy to use websocket.

Long question short: How to do long-polling in plain JS without jQuery or other framework? (Or is there a better way than long-polling).

Answer (score 2):

Is the following what you are looking for?

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';//or 'text', 'json', ect. there are other types. 
  xhr.timeout = 60000;//milliseconds until timeout fires. (1 minute)
  xhr.onload = function(e2){
    var blob = xhr.response;
    //handle response data
  }
  xhr.ontimeout = function(){
    //if you get this you probably should try to make the connection again.
    //the browser should've killed the connection. 
  }
  xhr.open('GET', "/path/to/URL.cmd?param1=val1&param2=val2", true);
  xhr.send();
```

I think the `timeout` attribute is the key to making the long-polls work, for more see the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20140130/#the-timeout-attribute) there are more information on the responseType's in the same document. If timeout is not specified, it's default value is zero.

Comment: So this is for the response as I have already read, but I want to know how I would be able to send data over the xhr when my app has the data ready, like calling xhr.send(data) multiple times, or is that not possible? (so that I will need to open up a new xhr every time I have data or queue the data eland send it very x seconds). So like in node where I can call .write multiple times and after it call .end

Comment: Perhaps, I've been giving it some thought. 

I've never played around with this, but there is a partial state `(xhr.readyState == 3)` I don't know much about browser implementation of it either. that said there is an [arrayBuffer called the responsive body](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20140130/#response-entity-body) that may be contain partial data until the readyState status is done.

So you may be able to do the .write call from the server several times and have it read and handled in partial segments. You could increase the timeout ms, recall same request `ontimeout`

Comment: That is what is already possible, I mean, when an XHR is open, (when neither ends closed it/ended it) I can call .write multiple times on the **server**, but my question is, how should I do such a thing from the **client**.

Comment: @ArtyMcFly don't forget the closing double quotes for xhr.open's path arg.